# how to change imageview in CollapsingToolbarLayout depending on each Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making app using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` first time.
I want change `Imageview`(in `ToolbarLayout`) when I clicked each tab.

I thought two solution. One is using `addOnTabSelectedListener`(but it is hard to find any example), two In each fragment, set each `Imageview`. does it make sense?

How should I change code?

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/yeouido0"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            app:tabContentStart="72dp"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**Fragment**

```
public class YeoidoFragment extends Fragment {


public YeoidoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.ganglist, container, false);

  final ArrayList<Gang> gangs = new ArrayList<>();
  gangs.add(new Gang(R.drawable.yeouido1, getString(R.string.chimek),getString(R.string.chimek_ex)));
  gangs.add(new Gang(R.drawable.yeouido2, getString(R.string.mulbit),getString(R.string.mulbit_ex)));
  gangs.add(new Gang(R.drawable.yeouido3, getString(R.string.flower),getString(R.string.flower_ex)));

   GangAdapter adapter = new GangAdapter(getActivity(), gangs);

    ListView listView= rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
    final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set the adapter onto the view pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    TabLayout tabLayout= findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // Connect the tab layout with the view pager. This will
    //   1. Update the tab layout when the view pager is swiped
    //   2. Update the view pager when a tab is selected
    //   3. Set the tab layout's tab names with the view pager's adapter's titles
    //      by calling onPageTitle()
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int position= tab.getPosition();


  }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You can set the image from onTabSelected like you mentioned. Get a reference to your ImageView and set your image to that ImageView in onTabSelected

Comment: @Mr.O I try this, is it alright?

int position= tab.getPosition();

    if(position==0) background.setImageResource(R.drawable.yeouido0);{
        if (position==1) background.setImageResource(R.drawable.banpo0);
        else background.setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
}

Comment: But I don’t see “background” declared in your code. Did you declare it?

Comment: @Mr.O Thanks for your reply. Finally I got it. 

I added this code

ImageView background = findViewById(R.id.HeaderImg);
                {  if (position == 0) background.setImageResource(R.drawable.yeouido0);

Comment: Alright anytime :) @young ban